# How to export BigQuery partitions to the GCS using Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partition

I need to create a Airflow job that exports the partitions in the BigQuery table to GCS between the given range of _PARTITIONDATE. I need partitions to be in separate file with the date of partitions. How can I achieve this?

I have tried using airflow tasks that uses SQL to fetch the _PARTITIONDATE, but can I do it programatically?

Answer (score 1):

For this, I recommend you to perform a loop in your dag definition (your loop is in Python code and you will add a lot of step in the DAG. By definition, the DAG can't contain loop).

The algorithm should be like that

- For all days in the range

  - Query BigQuery on this day and save the result to a temporary table, the name of the table contain the date. Use [BigqueryOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.html)
  - Extract the temporary table to GCS. Use [BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the link below
these are the guide to export Bigquery partitions to the GCS using Airflow:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wAyu5BN3VpY&t=28s

Comment: Please add more content to your answers, just a link to go look elsewhere is never enough: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer